# How can I do a buffer to those circuit?

Tags: amplifier, differential, buffer, cascode

I need to project a amplifier with 3 stages. First, a differencial pair with active load and current mirror. Second, a cascode and third, a buffer. I'm using BC547(npn) for differencial pair and BC557A(pnp) for active load, JFET BF245A for cascode. I need for input impedance 14250ohm, to get 85mW on output (required for project). My load is 64ohm and I can use a transformer. I got it untill the cascode, but i don't get anything from buffer, someone could helpme?

green dot = dc feed

yellow dot = dc block

dark blue dot = source, 20mV 20Hz-18kHz// source load = 350ohm

red 1-dot = 3820ohm

red 2-dot = 100ohm

red 3-dot = 105.79ohm

red 4-dot = 10Mohm

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 1):

What about DC voltage on BF245 gate? And, as I can see, this seems like semi-random circuit ;) Where is DC power of input stages? There is too much errors to describe them... Sorry.

Comment: Ok, nice start. I grounded first BF245 gate and put the output of the differencial pair in the gate of the second BF245. The DC power is in the first stage, I use a wire to put this voltage at differencial pair and the drain of first BF245

Comment: Not correct. The "upper" BF245 has grounded gate - it seems probably OK. But what about DC on the "lower" BF245? You connected the AC signal only, but totally forgot about proper gate polarisation, for example using resistor connected between this gate and ground.

Comment: The parts on the schematic are so far apart that the text is invisible.